# Modulo connect-flash no funciona

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, ejs

que tal? Estoy trabajando en un proyecto el cual necesito pasar mensajes del servidor al cliente, y he decidido utilizar el modulo Connect-Flash. Pero al momento de pasar el mensaje, el cliente no lo muestra. (Estoy utilizando el motor de plantillas EJS).

Este es mi **Index.ejs**

```
                <% if (message.lenght > 0) { %>
                    <p><%= message%></p>
                <% }%>
                <br>
                <form action="/signup" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="first_name">First name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="John">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                 <label for="last_name">Last name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Doe">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="JohnDoe123">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="example@example.com">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="******">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign in!" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">
                    <hr>
                    <div style="text-align: center">
                        <p>Already have an account? <a href="/signin">Sign up!</a></p>
                        <p>or go <a href="/">Home</a></p>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Este es mi **Index.js (NodeJS)**

```
app.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
    res.render('signup', {message: req.flash('error_msg')});
});

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    var first_name = req.body.first_name;
    var last_name = req.body.last_name;
    var username = req.body.username
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    var newUser = new User({
        first_name: first_name,
        last_name: last_name,
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password
    });

    User.findOne({username: newUser.username}, (err, username) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (username) {
            console.log('Username already taken');
            req.flash('error_msg', 'Username already taken!');
        }
        if (!username) {
            User.findOne({email: newUser.email}, (err, email) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (email) {
                    req.flash('error_msg', 'email already taken!');
                    console.log(req.flash('error_msg'))
                }
                if (!email) {
                    User.createUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
                        res.redirect('profile');
                        console.log(user);
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Se supone que el mensaje con el nombre 'error_msg' cuando un formulario es enviado y da un error (Si un usuario o email ya existe.). Pero cuando el formulario es enviado no solo no aparece el mensaje sino que tambien se queda como esperando a que pase algo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si utilizas render

```
res.render('signup', {message: req.flash('error_msg')});
```

puedes obtener la variable 'message' en javascript, asi:

```
let message=!JSON.stringify('message')
```

si envias

```
res.send({message: req.flash('error_msg')});
```

o con json

```
res.json({message: req.flash('error_msg')});
```

puedes obtenerlo asi:

`#{message}` directamente en la plantilla

Answer (score 0):

Es muchísimo mejor crear variables globales y así poder utilizarlas en toda la aplicación, antes de las rutas agrega

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();



app.use(flash());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   app.locals.errores = req.flash('errors');

    next();  //este next() hace que siga con el proceso y no se quede esperando una respuesta
});
```

Donde quieres agregar un error solo basta con agregar

```
req.flash('errors', '<Mensajes de error>'));
```

Y solo basta con llamar a la variable global llamada errores

```
<% if (errores) { %>
      <p><%= errores %></p>
<% }%>
```

como ves no hace falta agregar un `length` ya que si la variable esta vacía es `null` y `errores` no existe, de lo contrario contendrá el error que le envíes